# Same webview on every view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiwebview

Basically i have a webview on SecondViewController, and i wish for a small bit of this webview to be visible on every view like a tab bar.

Please note the webview will be on a webpage with a online slideshow so i cannot simply reload on each view

Thanks

Mason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try by placing the webView in MainWindow..

Comment: But how do i control from every view

Comment: Sorry for late reply, use appDelegate

Comment: But if its on mainwindow dosent that effect the tab bar